# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'RemoteMessage' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to the phone. The message is sent but the contents are not sent with the following error: Unhandled Exception: **NoSuchMethodError: Class 'RemoteMessage' has no instance method '[]'.**
There were a few similar questions but were of not much help. All suggestions shall be apprecated.

**pushNotificationService.dart**

```
   import 'package:driver/Models/rideDetails.dart';
    import 'package:driver/Notifications/notificationDialog.dart';
    import 'package:driver/configMaps.dart';
    import 'package:driver/main.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    import 'dart:io' show Platform;
    
    class PushNotificationService {
      final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    
      Future initialize(context) async {
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
          if (message.notification != null) {
            retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
          }
        });
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    
          retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
    
          });
      }
    
      Future<String?> getToken() async {
        String? token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
        driversRef.child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid).child("token").set(token);
    
        print("Here is your token");
        print(token);
    
        firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("alldrivers");
        firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("allusers");
      }
    
      String getRideRequestId(message) {
    
      // String getRideRequestId(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    
        String rideRequestId = "";
    
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          rideRequestId = message['data']['ride_request_id'];
        } else {
          rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
        }
        
        return rideRequestId;
      }
    
      void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId, BuildContext context) {
        newRequestRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
            double pickupLocationLat =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
            double pickupLocationLng =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString());
            String pickupAddress = dataSnapshot.value['pickup_address'].toString();
    
            double dropoffLocationLat =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['dropoff']['latitude'].toString());
            double dropoffLocationLng =
                double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['dropoff']['longitude'].toString());
            String dropoffAddress =
                dataSnapshot.value['dropoff_address'].toString();
    
            String paymentMethod = dataSnapshot.value['payment_method'].toString();
    
            String riderName = dataSnapshot.value["rider_name"].toString();
            String riderPhone = dataSnapshot.value["rider_phone"].toString();
    
            RideDetails rideDetails = RideDetails();
            rideDetails.ride_request_id = rideRequestId;
            rideDetails.pickup_address = pickupAddress;
            rideDetails.dropoff_address = dropoffAddress;
            rideDetails.pickup = LatLng(pickupLocationLat, pickupLocationLng);
            rideDetails.dropoff = LatLng(dropoffLocationLat, dropoffLocationLng);
            rideDetails.payment_method = paymentMethod;
            rideDetails.rider_name = riderName;
            rideDetails.rider_phone = riderPhone;
    
            print("Information :: ");
            print(rideDetails.pickup_address);
            print(rideDetails.dropoff_address);
    
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => NotificationDialog(rideDetails: rideDetails,),
            );
          }
        });
      }
    }
   

     **main.dart**

import 'package:driver/AllScreens/carInfoScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/configMaps.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/mainScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/registrationScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/DataHandler/appData.dart';

import 'AllScreens/loginScreen.dart';

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async
{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
DatabaseReference driversRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");
DatabaseReference newRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests");
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers").child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid).child("newRide");

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AppData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Driver',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? LoginScreen.idScreen : MainScreen.idScreen,
        routes: {
          RegistrationScreen.idScreen: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
          LoginScreen.idScreen: (context) => LoginScreen(),
          MainScreen.idScreen: (context) => MainScreen(),
          CarInfoScreen.idScreen: (context) => CarInfoScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  rideRequestId = message['data']['ride_request_id'];
} else {
  rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
}
```

to this

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  rideRequestId = message.data['ride_request_id'];
} else {
  rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
}
```